# Parsing JSON and save values to database in django

Tags: django-models, django-rest-framework

Am getting a post request from a ussd gateway. The post has a body in JSON format["phone":"07xxxxxx":"shortCode":"*100#":"text":"1"]
I need to parse this JSON,get individual values and save in django as a record. How do I go about this?

Comment: reading about `views` and `serializers` will get you started and a nice drf [tutorial](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/tutorial/quickstart/)

Answer (score 0):

next time please provide some code with what you tried so far. It shows other guys, that you at least tried to figure it out yourself. The problem you have is well documented in the DRF Tutorial and pretty straight forward. As you are new here on SO I will show it to you, but next time please put some more effort in it before writing a question.

You need four things:
-model
-serializer
-url
-view

The model represents the way your database table is built up. Based on your json data it could look like this:

**models.py**

```
from django.db import models

class ExampleModel(models.Model):
    phone = models.CharField(max_length=10)   # There are third party fields like django-phonenumber-field
    shortCode = models.CharField(max_length=10)
    text = models.CharField(max_length=50)
```

Then you need a serializer to handle your incoming json data and validate them. Create a serialzers.py file. In this example we use modelserializer, but there are some more like hyperlinkedmodelserializer or the serializer baseclass to create a fully custom serializer. For your purpose the modelserializer is a good way to go.

**serializers.py**

```
from rest_framework import serializers
from .models import ExampleModel

class ExampleModelSerializer(serializers.Modelserializer):
    class Meta:
        model = ExampleModel
        fields = '__all__'
```

Now we need a view. For your use case you need a view that handles the post request. I will use the generics.CreateAPIView. There is a lot that goes under the hood. You should do the tutorial to understand how you get from the APIView to the generic Views. Keep in mind that the CreateAPIView only handles the creation of new items. There are more generic views to handle list, retrieve, update and so on.

**views.py**

```
from rest_framework import generics
from .serializers import ExampleModelSerializer

class MyCreateView(generics.CreateAPIView):
    serializer_class = ExampleModelSerializer
```

The last thing you have to do is to define a url path.

**urls.py**

```
from django.urls import path
from yourappname import views

urlpatterns = [
    path('example/', views.MyCreateView.as_view()),
]
```

All of the things I wrote are covered in the tutorial.In the future, if something is not working and you could not solve it, provide a short example and you will find people to help you. But they won't write the entire code for you like I did this time. The reason I did it was that you are new and it was pretty straight forward to write it down. Good luck for you project.